# How to rectify the error while doing multiple inserts into postgres table using python3?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6

The python 3 code I used for inserting multiple records into postgresql is as follows:
Ignoring initializing the variables as necessary in below code, 'cur' is cursor object, 'conn' is the db connection object:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO logs(
                mfrom, mto,mstatus, mstatus_string)
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
                
row_dict = {
            "mfrom": mfrom,
            "mto": mto,
            "mstatus": mstatus,
            "mstatus_string": mstatus_string
           }        
mtup = tuple(row_dict.values())
list1.append(mtup)
val_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s,%s)', x).decode('utf-8') for x in list1)
try:
    cur.execute(sql, val_str)
    conn.commit()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    list1 = []
except Exception as e:
    conn.rollback()
    print(e, 'Error')
```

The error I get:

> not all arguments converted during string formatting Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by making changes in the sql, val_str and cur.execute statements as follows:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO logs(
          mfrom, mto,mstatus, mstatus_string)
          VALUES """ 

val_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s)", x).decode(
                        'utf-8') for x in list1)

cur.execute(sql + val_str)
```